# Использование классов

Tags: c#, wpf

Как такое бы выглядело с использованием своего класса для создания этих самых точек ?

В методе `OtrisovkaTochek()` меняется только положение этих самых точек на холсте.

А все остальные свойства ширина, высота, ширина контура, цвет контура, цвет заливки у них одинаковые.

Просто , маленький бы примерчик или учебный материал.

```
    Rectangle leftTopPoint = new Rectangle();           // Создание экземпляра левой верхней точки
    Rectangle rightTopPoint = new Rectangle();          // Создание экземпляра правой верхней точки
    Rectangle leftBottomPoint = new Rectangle();        // Создание экземпляра левой нижней точки
    Rectangle rightBottomPoint = new Rectangle();       // Создание экземпляра правой нижней точки

    // Метод отрисовывет точки
    private void OtrisovkaTochek()
    {
        // Левая верхняя точка
        leftTopPoint.Width = 7;                        // Ширина точки
        leftTopPoint.Height = 7;                       // Высота точки
        leftTopPoint.Stroke = Brushes.White;           // Цвет контура точки
        leftTopPoint.Fill = Brushes.Black;             // Цвет заливки точки
        leftTopPoint.StrokeThickness = 1;              // Толщина контура точки
        Canvas.SetLeft(leftTopPoint, x1 - 3);          // Положение точки по оси X
        Canvas.SetTop(leftTopPoint, y1 - 3);           // Положение точки по оси Y

        // Правая верхняя точка
        rightTopPoint.Width = 7;                         // Ширина точки
        rightTopPoint.Height = 7;                        // Высота точки
        rightTopPoint.Stroke = Brushes.White;            // Цвет контура точки
        rightTopPoint.Fill = Brushes.Black;              // Цвет заливки точки
        rightTopPoint.StrokeThickness = 1;               // Толщина контура точки
        Canvas.SetLeft(rightTopPoint, x2 - 4);           // Положение точки по оси X
        Canvas.SetTop(rightTopPoint, y2 - 3);            // Положение точки по оси Y

        // Левая нижняя точка
        leftBottomPoint.Width = 7;                       // Ширина точки
        leftBottomPoint.Height = 7;                      // Высота точки
        leftBottomPoint.Stroke = Brushes.White;          // Цвет контура точки
        leftBottomPoint.Fill = Brushes.Black;            // Цвет заливки точки
        leftBottomPoint.StrokeThickness = 1;             // Толщина контура точки
        Canvas.SetLeft(leftBottomPoint, x3 - 3);         // Положение точки по оси X
        Canvas.SetTop(leftBottomPoint, y3 - 4);          // Положение точки по оси Y

        // Правая нижняя точка
        rightBottomPoint.Width = 7;                       // Ширина точки
        rightBottomPoint.Height = 7;                      // Высота точки
        rightBottomPoint.Stroke = Brushes.White;          // Цвет контура точки
        rightBottomPoint.Fill = Brushes.Black;            // Цвет заливки точки
        rightBottomPoint.StrokeThickness = 1;             // Толщина контура точки
        Canvas.SetLeft(rightBottomPoint, x4 - 4);         // Положение точки по оси X
        Canvas.SetTop(rightBottomPoint, y4 - 4);          // Положение точки по оси Y
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого не надо писать класс, достаточно написать метод. Такой рефакторинг называется [Extract Method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html), используется для группировки функционала в одном методе, ну, или, как в данном случае, помещения повторяющегося кода в метод.

```
Rectangle leftTopPoint = new Rectangle();           // Создание экземпляра левой верхней точки
Rectangle rightTopPoint = new Rectangle();          // Создание экземпляра правой верхней точки
Rectangle leftBottomPoint = new Rectangle();        // Создание экземпляра левой нижней точки
Rectangle rightBottomPoint = new Rectangle();       // Создание экземпляра правой нижней точки

// Метод отрисовывет точки
private void OtrisovkaTochek()
{
    // Левая верхняя точка
    SetupRect(leftTopPoint, x1 - 3, y1 - 3);
    // Правая верхняя точка
    SetupRect(rightTopPoint, x2 - 4, y2 - 3);   
    // Левая нижняя точка
    SetupRect(leftBottomPoint, x3 - 3, y3 - 4);
    // Правая нижняя точка
    SetupRect(rightBottomPoint, x4 - 4, y4 - 4);
}

private void SetupRect(Rectangle target, double left, double top)
{
    target.Width = 7;                       // Ширина точки
    target.Height = 7;                      // Высота точки
    target.Stroke = Brushes.White;          // Цвет контура точки
    target.Fill = Brushes.Black;            // Цвет заливки точки
    target.StrokeThickness = 1;             // Толщина контура точки
    Canvas.SetLeft(target, left);         // Положение точки по оси X
    Canvas.SetTop(target, top);          // Положение точки по оси Y
}
```

Comment: Круто и так просто, спасибо! Думал для этого обязательно класс